# Change table header title design and style

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table whose output does not match my desired outcome. I want my table output to look like the table shown in the [Actual Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO0ns.png) image. Unfortunately, my table currently looks like the one in the [Wrong Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwAc6.png) image. Can someone help me modify my table header output?

ASP.NET

```
 <div class="right">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdDaily" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover sort display" 
        DataKeyNames="Daily_P21_ID" OnRowDeleting="grdDaily_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="true" OnRowCommand="grdDaily_RowCommand"
        OnPageIndexChanging="grdDaily_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" AllowSorting="true" OnRowDataBound="grdDaily_RowDataBound"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdDaily_SelectedIndexChanged1">
 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_On_Peak" HeaderText="On Peak" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Off_Peak" HeaderText="Off Peak" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="On_Peak" HeaderText="On Peak" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Off_Peak" HeaderText="Off Peak" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Demand" HeaderText="Max Demand" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Amp" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TX1_Amp" HeaderText="TX 1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TX2_Amp" HeaderText="TX 2" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MSB 1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MSB1_R" HeaderText="R" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MSB1_Y" HeaderText="Y" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MSB1_B" HeaderText="B" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MSB1_Voltage" HeaderText="Voltage" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />                  
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PBA" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PBA_City_Water" HeaderText="City Water, m3" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PBA_Hydrant" HeaderText="Hydrant, m3" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CDA" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CDA_Pressure" HeaderText="Pressure, bar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CDA_Dew_Point" HeaderText="Dew Point, °C" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="N2" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="N2_Pressure" HeaderText="Pressure, bar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="N2_Total_Volume" HeaderText="Total Volume, SCM" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="N2_Flow_Rate" HeaderText="Flowrate, SCM/h" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vacuum" HeaderText="Vacuum Pressure, in. Hg" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Chilled Water Supply" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Chilled_Supply_Temperature" HeaderText="Temperature, °C" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Chilled_Supply_Pressure" HeaderText="Pressure, psi" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Chilled Water Return" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Chilled_Return_Temperature" HeaderText="Temperature, °C" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Chilled_Return_Pressure" HeaderText="Pressure, psi" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 
            <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit" NavigateUrl="~/" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="xdd.aspx?ID={0}" FooterStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" />
            
            <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailSend" HeaderText="EmailSend" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false" />
 
        </Columns>
 
    </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

C#

```cs
protected void grdDaily_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        string item = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

        foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (button.CommandName == "Delete") 
            {
                button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };";
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= (grdDaily.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        grdDaily.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#ADD8E6");
    }
}
```

Comment: the cssclass table is doing its job, are you familiar with css ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Hi, I'm not familiar with but I try it and it doesn't get the output that I want as shown the image of Actual Table Output. Can you help me with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, about the best way to approach this?

Get the base table and grid working. Don't try and add the extra row heading as you have.

At the end (or start) of the day, you have one data table, you have ONE set of columns for the Gridview to render.

So, say I have this simple gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" Width="40%" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource =
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, let's now assume I want the header to have "Booking name", since that is first name, and last name.

And for the 2nd part, I could have Hotel Information.

So, we use the RowCreated event, and do this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Full Name";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Hotel Information";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

        }
    }
```

So, we added "2" new columns ABOVE the existing header.

The result is now this:

[image]

This may well mean your first 2 columns? Hum, not quite sure what to do there, maybe add columns without text.

So, you can in code add each of your "new" heading which will be placed on top of the actual table heading you already have.

There are "many" examples of adding a extra header row, but I find the above is  about the most workable. Not ideal, not perfect, but it is a working approach here.